# how to change the data type in a text file with each row having a dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a file (say, `"data.txt"`) that has around 25k lines. Each line is a JSON representation of a `dict` with various fields. The datatype in these dictionaries has some parameters like `height`, `width`, `depth`, `qty` that are incorrectly represented as a `string` rather than an `int` or a `float` value. I would like to change these parameter data types to either `float` or `int`. Is there a way a simple way to change all these parameters in this file?

```
{ "seller_cd":"20559","order_cd":"121213123123","items":[{"item_cd":"45114","item_name":"ABC","width":"16.9","height":"3.4","depth":"13.8", "qty":"3"},{"item_cd":"4232","item_name":"xyz","width":"16.9","height":"1.5", "depth":"11.8","qty":"3"},{"item_cd":"45114","item_name":"xz","width":"16.6","height":"3.9","depth":"13.7","qty":"6"}]}
{ "seller_cd":"20559","order_cd":"121213123123","items":[{"item_cd":"45114","item_name":"ABC","width":"16.9","height":"3.4","depth":"13.8", "qty":"3"},{"item_cd":"4232","item_name":"xyz","width":"16.9","height":"1.5", "depth":"11.8","qty":"3"},{"item_cd":"45114","item_name":"xz","width":"16.6","height":"3.9","depth":"13.7","qty":"6"}]}
{ "seller_cd":"20559","order_cd":"121213123123","items":[{"item_cd":"45114","item_name":"ABC","width":"16.9","height":"3.4","depth":"13.8", "qty":"3"},{"item_cd":"4232","item_name":"xyz","width":"16.9","height":"1.5", "depth":"11.8","qty":"3"},{"item_cd":"45114","item_name":"xz","width":"16.6","height":"3.9","depth":"13.7","qty":"6"}]}
.
.
.
20K lines like these
```

I have tried to use a json library but I was unable to tackle the problem. Note that the whole file is not a valid JSON dump, but rather a collection of lines, each of which is a JSON dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: added a way to limit conversion of `dict` values to only a subset of keys.

Here is way that cleans dicts by trying to cast to various types after loading each line as a json value. It is extensible in that you can add more types if you like (for this example, just `int` and `float`).

```py
def clean_dict(x, types=(int, float), keys=None):
    """Try to recursively convert all values to one of the types.
    If keys is specified, dict values are only converted if the key matched
    of if they are a list or dict.
    """
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        return {
            clean_dict(k, keys=keys): clean_dict(v, keys=keys) if keys is None or k in keys
            or isinstance(v, (list, dict)) else v
            for k, v in x.items()
        }
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return [clean_dict(v, keys=keys) for v in x]
    for typ in types:
        try:
            return typ(x)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return x
```

Quick test:

```py
>>> clean_dict({'1.1': 'foo', 'bar': ['3', '4.5']})
{1.1: 'foo', 'bar': [3, 4.5]}
```

**Application**:

```py
filename = 'data.txt'
outfile = 'data-modified.txt'

only_keys = {'width', 'height', 'depth', 'qty'}
with open(filename) as fin, open(outfile, 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        dct = json.loads(line)
        dct = clean_dict(dct, keys=only_keys)
        json.dump(dct, fout)
        fout.write('\n')
```

**Example**:

```py
txt = """{ "seller_cd":"20559","order_cd":"121213123123","items":[{"item_cd":"45114","item_name":"ABC","width":"16.9","height":"3.4","depth":"13.8", "qty":"3"},{"item_cd":"4232","item_name":"xyz","width":"16.9","height":"1.5", "depth":"11.8","qty":"3"},{"item_cd":"45114","item_name":"xz","width":"16.6","height":"3.9","depth":"13.7","qty":"6"}]}
{ "seller_cd":"20559","order_cd":"121213123123","items":[{"item_cd":"45114","item_name":"ABC","width":"16.9","height":"3.4","depth":"13.8", "qty":"3"},{"item_cd":"4232","item_name":"xyz","width":"16.9","height":"1.5", "depth":"11.8","qty":"3"},{"item_cd":"45114","item_name":"xz","width":"16.6","height":"3.9","depth":"13.7","qty":"6"}]}
{ "seller_cd":"20559","order_cd":"121213123123","items":[{"item_cd":"45114","item_name":"ABC","width":"16.9","height":"3.4","depth":"13.8", "qty":"3"},{"item_cd":"4232","item_name":"xyz","width":"16.9","height":"1.5", "depth":"11.8","qty":"3"},{"item_cd":"45114","item_name":"xz","width":"16.6","height":"3.9","depth":"13.7","qty":"6"}]}
"""

filename = 'test.txt'
outfile = 'test-modified.txt'

# first, write our test file
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(txt)

# now the conversion
only_keys = {'width', 'height', 'depth', 'qty'}
with open(filename) as fin, open(outfile, 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        dct = json.loads(line)
        dct = clean_dict(dct, keys=only_keys)
        json.dump(dct, fout)
        fout.write('\n')

# finally
! cat $outfile
```

produces:

```
{"seller_cd": "20559", "order_cd": "121213123123", "items": [{"item_cd": "45114", "item_name": "ABC", "width": 16.9, "height": 3.4, "depth": 13.8, "qty": 3}, {"item_cd": "4232", "item_name": "xyz", "width": 16.9, "height": 1.5, "depth": 11.8, "qty": 3}, {"item_cd": "45114", "item_name": "xz", "width": 16.6, "height": 3.9, "depth": 13.7, "qty": 6}]}
{"seller_cd": "20559", "order_cd": "121213123123", "items": [{"item_cd": "45114", "item_name": "ABC", "width": 16.9, "height": 3.4, "depth": 13.8, "qty": 3}, {"item_cd": "4232", "item_name": "xyz", "width": 16.9, "height": 1.5, "depth": 11.8, "qty": 3}, {"item_cd": "45114", "item_name": "xz", "width": 16.6, "height": 3.9, "depth": 13.7, "qty": 6}]}
{"seller_cd": "20559", "order_cd": "121213123123", "items": [{"item_cd": "45114", "item_name": "ABC", "width": 16.9, "height": 3.4, "depth": 13.8, "qty": 3}, {"item_cd": "4232", "item_name": "xyz", "width": 16.9, "height": 1.5, "depth": 11.8, "qty": 3}, {"item_cd": "45114", "item_name": "xz", "width": 16.6, "height": 3.9, "depth": 13.7, "qty": 6}]}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I did not get any output for the `application` part of the code. `data-modified.txt` is blank

Comment: @Sam: what version of Python are you running?

Comment: I am using python 3.6

Comment: Then that should work without any problem. Try to debug or put a print statement in the `for line in fin` loop (and break). I wonder if `data.txt` is empty or what. What happens if you try exactly the "example" portion (in another directory)?

Comment: oh ya. my `data.txt` file was empty. It is working perfectly fine. Thanks a lot. Is it possible to just change the data type for  `"width": 16.9, "height": 1.5, "depth": 11.8, "qty": 3` part ?

Comment: I don't understand your last comment?

Comment: actually, this program converted all the values to `integer` type.  `seller_cd` and the `order_cd` and `item_cd` was supposed to be a string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228684/discussion-between-sam-and-pierre-d).

Comment: Ok, I see. Added a `keys` argument to limit the scope of conversion.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  One of the parameters `item_name` is also affected during this conversion. It is giving me some random string although we are not changing anything in that. `item_name` is mostly a Japanese character that is not being rendered as a Japanese character but with some random string. I tried adding the utf-8 encoding but did not work. Do I have to change something while loading the file?

Comment: fixed it using `ensure_ascii=False`

Comment: I just checked that the `item_cd` is not a string although you are not changing the data type for that. Is there any specific reason? It should have been a string.

Comment: sorry about that, I had forgotten to pass the `keys` along. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

A naive and possibly brittle way would be to use regex to match on the numbers with `"` and remove them by replacement. This assumes all other fields are not numbers and floats.

```py
import re
num_pattern = re.compile(r'"(\d+|\d*\.\d+)"')
with open(...) as file:
    lines = [num_pattern.sub(r'\1', line) for line in file]

# json parse logic
```

Operating on the string representation and then relying on the highly optimized json parser should be faster than traversing the data structure with naive python.